# Expected expression error in simple for loop C

Tags: c, parse-error

I am getting an "expected expression" error on the line where I try to assign `char(x)` to `letter`.

My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    char letter;
    for(int x=97; x<=122; x++){
        letter = char(x);  //error occurs on this line
        printf("%c\n", letter);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: That't not how you cast variables. Try `letter = (char)x;`

Comment: BTW, you don't need the cast at all there. `letter = x` will work as well

Comment: The notation `char(x)` is valid in C++, but not in C.  In C, you must use `(char)x` notation to cast, though there's no need for the cast in the first place (`letter = x;` would work fine)

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to typecast, you must do:

```
(char)x;
```

Not

```
char(x);
```

Comment: Note that C++ allows (though no longer encourages) the `char(x)` notation as an alternative cast.  However, you're right that C does not allow that.

Answer (score 3):

You are explicitly typecasting but while doing this you are using C++ notation.

Change that line to this:

```
letter = (char)x;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change `x` into a `char`, you don't need to typecast `x`.

```
letter = x;
```

Another elimination, you can drop letter altogether and use:

```
printf("%c\n", x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just avoid unnecessary casting, and also to have a cleaner code:

```
for(int x='a'; x<='z'; x++){
    printf("%c\n", x);
}
```

No need for `char letter` at all, no need for *magic numbers*.